# ADB2C Read extension properties us SignInWithMagicLink Custome Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using the Custom Policy for signing with SignInWithMagicLink here
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/sign-in-with-magic-link/policy/SignInWithMagicLink.xml

I have extension properties defined in ADB2C, however I am unable to read them using above custom policy. It makes use of AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress Technical profile to read the claims. I have added my extension property as an output claim, but the value is not being read.
Can any body figure out why this is not working?

I have added the output claim for extension property here

```
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Azure Active Directory</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress">
          <Metadata>
            <!--Sample: don't raise error if user not found. We have an orchestration step to handle the error message-->
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">false</Item>
            <Item Key="client_id">...</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <OutputClaims>
            <!--Sample: add optional claims to read from the directory-->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_crmid" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
  </ClaimsProviders>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some digging I found that the clientId I was sending to AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress was incorrect.

To be able to make available extension attributes to Technical Profiles like UserReadUsingEmailAddress  AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId, we have to specify the ClientId and ObjectId of the b2c-extensions-app found under App Registrations > All Applications.

So, I removed client_id from Metadata of AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress, and instead added it under AAD-Common TechnicalProfile that is referenced by UserReadUsingEmailAddress  AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId

```
    <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-Common">
      <DisplayName>Azure Active Directory</DisplayName>
         <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ApplicationObjectId">b2c-extensions-app object id</Item>
        <Item Key="ClientId">b2c-extensions-app client id</Item>
      </Metadata>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

This information is provided below:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-create-custom-attributes-profile-edit-custom